# Why does my function return 0 instead of the number of lines in a file?

Tags: c

I have written a function that is supposed to read the number of sentences in a .txt file, but when the function is called and done, it gives me a value of 0.

This program over all has 3 more functions to figure out different properties of the file and I have them working great. This one is laid out the same way I wrote my other functions just looking for some advice on why I am getting 0 as my number of sentences.

```
void ptrCntS (FILE* sp1, int sCount)
{
    char sentence = 'O';
    int myChr;

    if (!(sp1 = fopen("Hello.txt", "r")))
    {
        printf("error opening Hello.txt");
        return(1);
    }

    while ((myChr = fgetc(sp1)) != EOF)
    {
        if ('.') 
        {
            sentence ='O';
        } 
        else if (sentence == 'O')
        {
            sCount++;
            sentence = 'I';
        }
    }

    fclose(sp1);
    printf ("Total number of sentences are:\t%d", sCount);

    return;
}
```

Comment: What did you see while debugging?

Comment: Don't pass in a local variable as argument. `sp1` has no meaning outside this function, so it should be a local variable, not an argument.

Comment: What do you think that `if ('.')` will do?

Comment: if (myChr == '.') instead of if ('.'), no ?

Comment: Do that code compile without errors? How can you return with a value in a function declared as returning `void`?

Comment: Shouldn't `return(1);` give you a compilation error since the return type is `void`?

Comment: The same goes for `sCount`. If you want to see changes to it in the calling function, you should pass a pointer to an `int`, through which you can modify that int. A more straightforward approach woud be to return the count instead of having a `void` function.

Comment: take a look at this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21513043/counting-the-number-of-sentences-in-a-paragraph-in-c

Comment: "*This one is laid out the same way I wrote my other functions*" - this sounds to me like you're having here a few copy & paste errors that do not work for the functionality you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

instead of return use return(sCount);
and assign the return value to some int variable in calling function
like
int sentCount;
.
.
.
sentCount=ptrCntS (param1,param2);

Answer (score 0):

if ('.') is always true, thus else... code never reached. Use if( myChr == '.' ) instead.

Comment: Thank you this fixed my issue Now all functions being called are sending back the appropiate numbers just need to get one last function figured out to display them all

Answer (score 0):

Function compiles now and runs properly. This function is being called from a switch in a previous function where I had my addresses set and included my print statement for the totals so that I would not have to write another function in the end to call on all my counts and print their results. Instead I set my case 'A': to call all of my counting functions(in this case that is what the original code is) and than display my results. I am sorry for any lengthiness or my hard to understand writing I am new to the C language and I am having a hard time grasping the literature but making some process on understanding the syntax.